# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having some issues with a bit of code which I'm getting a type error 
which is `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` Should I be using an `if` state rather that a `for` statement?

What I'm trying to achieve is if `on_message` a message has been pinned for 7 days or more then unpin that message.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Listen for a message then unpin any other messages older than 7 days"""
    server = message.server
    channelid = '490899209067823135'
    limit_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    if server:
        for message.content in message.channel.id == channelid:
            if limit_date:
                try:
                    await self.bot.unpin_message(message)

                except discord.Forbidden:
                    print("No permissions to do that!")
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: `for message.content in message.channel.id == channelid:` - what do you think the result of `message.channel.id == channelid` is? Though that entire line doesn't make much sense to me

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, `message.channel.id == channelid` evaluates to a boolean value either `True` or `False`. So your `for` loop becomes either

```
for message.content in True
```

or

```
for message.content in False
```

The right side of `in` here must be some iterable. The compiler complains because it isn't.

To suggest a solution to this problem, we need more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

```
for message.content in message.channel.id == channelid:
```

The == is *checking* whether mess.age.channel.id and channelid are equal, and so your statemnts effectively becomes

```
for message.content in true:
```

or

```
for message.content in false:
```

A for loop goes through every element in a list or similar structure, so it cannot take a boolean after the 'in'

My guess would that you separately want to *assign* channelid to message.channel.id, then loop through it. e.g.

```
message.channel.id = channelid
for message.content in message.channel.id:
```

Answer (score 0):

`for message.content in message.channel.id == channelid:`

Perhaps you mean to have

```
if message.channel.id == channelid:
    for message.content in message.channel.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, because `message.channel.id == channelid` either returns `True` or `False`, your for loop essentially becomes either
    for message.content in True
or
    for message.content in False

I suppose what you are trying to achieve here is looping over `message`s whose `message.channel.id` is equal to `channelid`. Because you're getting one `message` passed as an argument of function `on_message`, you do not need a loop at all because you don't have *multiple* `message`s to iterate over *in `on_message` itself*. The loop must be outside, where `on_message` is called, that is; or get a list of `message`s passed as an argument.

For your code, you can simply change

```
for message.content in message.channel.id == channelid:
```

to

```
if message.channel.id == channelid:
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers give you a good insight into why your code doesn't work but here is how you could implement what you want:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
  """Listen for a message then unpin any other messages older than 7 days"""
  messages = await self.bot.pins_from(self.bot.get_channel('490899209067823135'))
  for msg in messages:
    if (datetime.now() - msg.timestamp).days > 7:
      try:
        await self.bot.unpin_message(msg)
  except discord.Forbidden:
    print("No permissions to do that!")
```

Comment: When I add `if server:` before the line `for msg in messages:` I will get a `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'server'`

Comment: Did you add the `server = message.server` above?